# When camera on, OnBackPressed() in android

Tags: android, android-camera

I am accessing mobile camera in my application to capture an image. Here I want when i click on camera(button) it will open the camera of the mobile device to capture. Before capturing the image, that means ofter open camera I want to call Onbackpressed() method which should go back to the home page of my application. How should I achieve this.

Thanks,
Ram

Comment: why would you want to open the camera only for closing it again?

Answer (score 1):

Goddchen is right ,why are you opening it for closing.. anyway no need to call onbackpressed() set the intent for homepage after opening camera.